# Getting Rid of .Find in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of two columns that I want to search for a "key" and then find the corresponding value in the directly adjacent column. The key is stored in a dictionary that I populated earlier in the program. I then store the value with its corresponding key in the dictionary to display later.

I am using `.Find` to search the range for the key and then getting the value using `.Offset` to get the adjacent cell. The code follows:

```
Dim key As Variant
Dim filRange As Range
Dim found As Range

Set filRange = ws.Range("D2:E36419").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
 
Dim count As Integer
Dim i As Long
 
For i = 0 To partsDict.count - 1
    key = partsDict.Keys(i)
    Set found = filRange.Find(key)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        count = found.Offset(0, 1).value
        partsDict(i) = count
    Else
        partsDict(i) = Empty
    End If

Next i
```

The code functions as expected and I am able to print all values later in the program. The issue is the program takes over 15 seconds to run. I've seen the `.Find` method is slow and feel like there is a better way to search and retrieve my values. Should I store the range in an array somehow? Use another dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: Cant you create a named table for the D:E entries and then search on the named table? This should reduce the search to actually used cells instead of 72k cells.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned. I filtered the table before the loop and the range being searched is just the visible cells after the filtering. In the current iteration there are ~16,500 cells in the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things will speed up this:

- read the sheet data into an internal array and work on that
- use an auxiliary dict for searching

like this

```
Sub list2dict()
    ' 2020-07-02
    
        Dim key As Variant
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        
        Dim NewpartsDict As Dictionary
        Set NewpartsDict = New Dictionary
    
        ' Set ws = ...
        
        ' read range data into array
        ' SpecialCells... might contain several areas!
        Dim myData
        Dim partrange As Range
        
        For Each partrange In ws.Range("D2:E36419").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
            myData = partrange
            ' store array data into auxiliary dict
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To UBound(myData, 1)
                NewpartsDict(myData(i, 1)) = myData(i, 2) ' dict(key) = value
            Next i
        Next partrange

        ' update partsDict's existing entries
        For Each key In partsDict
            If NewpartsDict.Exists(key) Then  ' a.k.a. Find()
                partsDict(key) = NewpartsDict(key)
            Else
                partsDict(key) = Empty
            End If
        Next key
        
        ' optional: add new entries
        For Each key In NewpartsDict
            If Not partsDict.Exists(key) Then
                partsDict(key) = NewpartsDict(key)
            End If
        Next key
        
        ' now use the updated data in partsDict
    End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like something I could use. However, I am getting a type mismatch error in the first for-loop using UBound. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: he OP is working with filtered data which will often consist of noncontinuous ranges. The Range that is return by`SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` consists of 1 Area for each continuous set of cells.  In you example, `myData` is only referring to the values of the first area of the target range.  In order for an array based approach to work, you will need to iterate over each area of the target range.

Comment: yes, of course. I will work on that, it's not complicated.

Comment: I've added a loop over all `.areas` of the visible range, as suggested by @TinMan (thanks!).

Comment: @user1016274 I am having some trouble with updating the partsDict's existing entries. Newpartsdict populates fine and has all elements in it. However, after updating partsDict, less than 10 keys have values mapped to them. Weird issue.

Comment: The key search needs to be case-insensitive. You can set a dictionary property to enable this: `dict.CompareMode = vbTextMode` right after `Set NewpartsDict = New Dictionary`. `range.find()` is case-insensitive by default.

Comment: Is Newpartsdict.CompareMode = TextCompare the same thing? If it is, I still have the same issue. I get a runtime error using vbTextMode

Comment: The issue was the type of the keys for the two dictionaries. The keys of Newpartdict were being stored as strings while partsDict's keys were doubles. Just had to convert partsDict keys to strings and everything worked.

Comment: Good you spotted this, I was about to ask for data source samples to debug it. Hope it works satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Set filRange = ws.Range("D2:E36419").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
> ```

Hard coding range references will makes your code unnecessarily inflexible.  It is best to create a dynamic range reference that will resize itself to fit the data.

> ```
> With ws
>     Set filRange = .Range("D2:E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
> End With
> ```

The `filRange`  is set to 2 columns.  I am assuming that column 1 is the key column and column 2 is the value column.  If this is the case then you should either adjust your fill range:

> ```
> With ws
>     Set filRange = .Range("D2" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
> End With
> ```

Or adjust your search:

> ```
> Set found = filRange.Columns(1).Find(key)
> ```

`Range.CurrentRegion` is a convenient way to create a dynamic range.

> Set filRange = ws.CurrentRegion.Columns("D")

### Question:

> Do we think putting every pair in a new Dictionary structure would work? I'm thinking once everything is in the Dictionary, searching for my keys should be quick (does Dictionary use hashing?).

### Answer:

Yes and yes.  Dictionaries use hashing for super fast look ups.  You may find this article interesting [EXCEL VLOOKUP VS INDEX MATCH VS SQL VS VBA](https://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/).

The reason that we use dictionaries in the first place is for the super fast look ups.  The problem in your project setup is that you are using `Range.Find()` for your lookups.
Its hard to give advice about what is the best approach with just a small snippet of code. Proving a more detailed question with all your relevant code, data samples, and perhaps a test stub will give you the best results.

### Solution

Whatever you decide to do the key is to loop over the range values once and use the dictionary lookup up the values.  Personally, I would write a function that returns a dictionary that holds the filtered keys and values and compare it to `partsDict`.

```
Function GetFilteredRangeMap(Target As Range, KeyColumn As Variant, ValueColumnOffset As Variant) As Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim Column As Range
    
    Rem Set Column to the Visible Cells in the Key Column Range
    With Target.CurrentRegion.Columns(KeyColumn)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Column = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    
    If Not Column Is Nothing Then
        Dim Map As New Scripting.Dictionary
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In Column
            Map(KeyPrefix & Cell.Value) = Cell.Offset(ValueColumnOffset)
        Next
    End If
    
    Set GetFilteredRangeMap = Map
End Function
```

### Usage

> ```
> Dim Target As Range
> Set Target = Sheet2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
>
> Dim Map As New Scripting.Dictionary
> Set Map = GetFilteredRangeMap(Target, 1, 2)
> ```

Comment: GetFilteredRangeMap() did the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable culprit for your performance issues are the constant context switches betwwe vba and Excel whenever you call find. Depending on the number of keys in your dictionary, this can add up.

One thing you could try is to load the entire `filRange` into a 2d array via the range's `Value` property. Then you could search that. Unfortunately, there is no built-in support for that. You could sort the array and then use a binary search for every key.

One other thing I observed in your code is that you access the dictionary in a way it really is not built for. A dictionary is  built to be accessed by key.

The first thing you can do is to use a `For Each` loop on `partsDict.Keys`, i.e. `For Each key in partsDict.Keys`. Then, when you assign the values, you can do it by key, i.e. `partsDict(key) = whatever` or `partsDict.Item(key)`, which is what the first one complies to.

Comment: Do we think putting every pair in a new Dictionary structure would work? I'm thinking once everything is in the Dictionary, searching for my keys should be quick (does Dictionary use hashing?).